# move all files in a directory that have less than X lines

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to move all files in a directory that have less than X lines (in my case 6)

I tried :

```
find /path/folder/ -type f -exec awk -v lines=6 'NR>lines{f=1; exit} END{exit !f}' {} \; -exec echo mv output_folder/ {} \;
```

But it's not working, any files is moved. Any tips?

Comment: You need to invoke a shell to run shell commands after the `-exec`

Comment: That said, you don't need `awk` to count total lines in a text file.

Comment: "_Is not working_" is probably the worst possible problem description. Please edit your question and add a clear description of what happens and why it is wrong. Anyway, your `{f=1; exit}` is the problem. Try `awk -v lines=6 'NR>lines {exit 1}'`.

Comment: @Jetchisel No, you don't need to invoke a shell with `-exec`, the parameter is passed to the shell. What the OP have is almost correct. Their problem is just a wrong use of the `awk` `exit` action.

Comment: Ok. I stand corrected, but still having two `-exec` does not seem to be a good approach.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Haha sorry, I was in hurry when I posted my question. I edited.
Any files is moved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is tagged as `bash`.

```
find /path/folder -type f -exec sh -c '
  for f; do
    total_count=$(wc -l < "$f")
    if [ "$total_count" -lt 6 ]; then
      echo mv -vn -- "$f" /destination
    fi
  done' _ {} +
```

---

In one line.

```
find /folder/path -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do total_count=$(wc -l < "$f"); if [ "$total_count" -lt 6 ]; then echo mv -vn -- "$f" /destination; fi; done' _ {} +
```

---

- Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output.
- See [understanding-the-exec-option-of-find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

Comment: working well ! Thank you